# Problems splitting a string to get authentication and command

Tags: arduino-uno, c, string

Good afternoon,

In a nutshell I'm having some difficulty with splitting and returning part of a string.

Essentially I'm working on the code for transmitting a password (24 character string) and command (string) in a single packet. However, the 'get_command' function is only returning the first character of the string (T) as opposed to the whole string (T1) and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The entire sketch is below so you should be able to just drop it in and compile.

```
char *received_data = "KkV3vKvLgC4PdBZRs5kkKM86T1";
char *password = "KkV3vKvLgC4PdBZRs5kkKM86";

int authenticate_transmission(char *data) {
    if(strncmp(data, password, 24)) {
        Serial.println("no match");
        return false;
    } else {
        Serial.println("match");
        return true;
    }
}

char *get_command(char *data) {
    char command[3];
    strncpy(command, data + 24, 3);
    // Fine here
    Serial.println(command);
    return command;
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // test received data - message is T1 at the end.
    if (authenticate_transmission(received_data)) {
        char *command = get_command(received_data);
        // But just prints out first char when returned from a function
        Serial.println(*command);
    }
    delay(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `command` array created inside `get_command()` is local data. That means it's only available while that function is being executed.

However, you're returning a pointer to it. That means when you're trying to use `command` afterwards from inside `loop()`, you're trying to refer to data which has been deallocated. By that point, it's getting used for something else.

There are various solutions to this. A fairly simple approach would be to have the caller allocate the `command` array, passing a pointer to it into `get_command()`. For example:

```cpp
void get_command(char *data, char *command) {
    strncpy(command, data + 24, 3);
}
```

From `loop()`, you would call it like this:

```cpp
char command[3];
get_command(received_data, command);
```

The `command` array is still local data in this case. However, it's local to the `loop()` function (or wherever else you put that code). That means it will still be available when `get_command()` is called.

Comment: Saying `static char command[3]` instead is slightly easier

Comment: @jwpat7 That would work, but it's not good programming practice.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's very helpful. I've got it all sorted now and a bit more insight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The direct issue is you have a dereference operator (`*`) in the loop that you don't need:

```
Serial.println(*command);
```

This causes it to pass **only the first character** to `Serial.println()` instead of the pointer to the memory location. That's the first issue.

Like Peter mentioned, the string gets deallocated when returned from the `get_command()` function. It's undefined behavior, but it's luck that it worked the way it did.

Comment: Good catch. Hadn't spotted that myself.